# access other mac's time machine drive and backup macbook with wireless adhoc

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, backup, time-machine

I have 1 **iMac with external time machine drive** and **1 macbook air**.

My iMac's external time machine drive is active and I know 1 disk can be use for multiple mac's backup.

I want to backup my macbook air datas same external drive over on my iMac with wireless connection.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the operating system on your iMac to OSX Server.

Then your iMac "can act as a designated Time Machine backup location for all the Mac computers on your network."

Check out http://www.apple.com/osx/server/features/#time-machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bob, but i don't want to use OSX Server.
i just want to share my time machine disk and backup my other mac's disk.